# A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'., when using Knockout, MVC, and Kendo

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, kendo-ui

We have an application in MVC (.NET 4.5.1) using Kendo and Knockout.
It was working fine until last week, when we **upgraded the Kendo library from 2018 to 2020**. (2020.2.617).

Now, we are getting this error all the time in the **Application_Error** in **Global.asax**:

> A public action method 'undefined' was not found on controller 'Web.Controllers.HomeController'

This is the relevant code causing the issue, which I have copy/paste in other pages of the application to test, and I'm always getting the same error in the Global.asax.

```
<div id="divId" data-bind="kendoWindow: { isModal: true, widget: widget }">
    <textarea id="dummyId" data-bind="kendoEditor: { value: 'title', widget: editor} "></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.editor = ko.observable();
        self.widget = ko.observable();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new test(), document.getElementById("divId"));

</script>
```

If I removed one of the components, either the KendoWindow either the KendoEditor, it is not giving the exception.

We are loading all new kendo libraries than before the upgrade in the BundleConfig.cs.

Any idea which can be the cause of this and how can it be fixed? Going back to Kendo 2018, is not an option anymore.

Comment: So I don't know much about MVC, but why would you have a back-end error in front-end code? If either one works, maybe the binding firing first is somehow modifying the HTML so that the second one is failing?

Comment: Actually, everything is working as expected and no error is given in the screen. The problem is that somehow it is reaching the back-end with that error. I'm still investigating but I'm almost sure that it is a problem with the new Kendo 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just seen there is a fix in the latest release of Kendo (2020.3.915) that will fix the problem:

https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r3-2020?_ga=2.175661665.2102584926.1606749571-1674673946.1605197457

[image: Kendo documentation]